# My program bounces back and forth between for and if, I have no idea why

Tags: pascal, lazarus, freepascal

I'm doing some homework and there's this problem where I have to make a program that tells me how many prime numbers there are between two numbers given by the user. For some reason, when I test the program with F8 I can see the program bounces back and forth between "for" and "if", for no apparent reason. And yes, I HAVE to use this language.

I have tried restanting the IDE, hoping it'ts just some bug (like it often happens on Android Studio). I don't know what else to try, this is the first time I use Lazarus and PASCAL.

```
program PrimoEntre;
var
  a, b, i, q: Integer;
begin
  write('Ingrese el primer valor: ');
  readln(a);
  write('Ingrese el segundo valor: ');
  readln(b);

  for i:=a to b do  //It starts bouncing back and forth from here...
      begin
        q:=2;
        if((b>=2)AND(b<=10)) then //...to here.
                            begin
                              while((q>=2) and (q<=b)) do
                              begin
                                if(a<>b) then
                                        begin
                                           if((a MOD b)=0) then
                                           begin;
                                            //i ES NO PRIMO
                                            if(q=b) then
                                                   begin
                                                        writeln('No existen numeros primos entre ', a, ' y ', b, '.');
                                                   end;
                                          q:=(q+1);
                                           end;

                                        end
                                else
                                           begin
                                            if(q=b) then
                                              begin
                                              //i ES PRIMO
                                              writeln(i, ' es primo.');;
                                              q:=1
                                              end;
                                            end;
                              end;
                            end

        else
                            begin
                              while((q>=2) and (b<=10)) do
                              begin
                                if(a<>b) then
                                        begin
                                           if((a MOD b)=0) then
                                           begin
                                            //i ES NO PRIMO
                                            if(q=b) then
                                                   begin
                                                        writeln('No existen numeros primos entre ', a, ' y ', b, '.');
                                                   end;
                                          q:=(q+1);
                                           end;
                                        end
                                else
                                           begin
                                            if(q=b) then
                                              begin
                                              //i ES PRIMO
                                              writeln(i, ' es primo.');
                                              q:=1
                                              end
                                           end;
                              end;
                            end;
      end;
readln();
end.
```

I expect the output to be one of the following:
-The console writing every time it finds a prime number between a and b.
-The console saying there isn't any prime number between a and b.

Instead, there's no result. The program just gets stuck and I have to terminate it manually.

Comment: Depends on your input. If you enter 11 for b, for instance, there's no branch that the execution can enter and modify the condition and so the program will loop forever. Even in pascal.

Comment: Doesn't the "else" take care of that? I'm pretty sure it does, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: The else has only one block which has a "while b<=10" again, so it doesn't prevent the endless loop. Still, if the compiler is not discarding unused code you'd be seeing the line on the while too. Search for some compiler optimization setting in your IDE, you'd want to turn it off.

Comment: You can understand the way a program works by examining its execution flow, and inspecting its variables, using a debugger. I recommend that you spend a little time exploring your program this way.

Comment: What @DavidHeffernan says. You should re-think your code and iteratively simplify it until you can see where your errors are: There is no point continually executing `f((a MOD b)=0) then` inside your  `for` loop - either it is true or it is not before the loop executes or it is not.  You might also take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Answer (score 1):

You say you are trying to find prime numbers in the range a...b.  The problem is that
you are doing this in a quite unnecessarily complicated way and the main reason
your program is jumping all over the place is that you are making it do so because
you are making the value of your `q` variable jump all over the place.

What I think you should do it to slow down and think what you are trying to do:

- You want to iterate the integers in the range `a` to `b`.  Your `for` loop does
  this fine, with the value of `i` being what you are testing for primality. I'm going
  to refer to this as your outer `for` loop.
- Where you go wrong is to needlessly execute a `while` loop to test for primality.
- Once you have established the `i` value you are testing, what you want to do is to
  test whether there is any factor of `i` which is other than 1 or `i`.  To do that, you
  can use a simple, inner `for` loop which iterates a value `j` (so-called to avoid
  confusion with your `q`) to determine whether `i` is divisible by `j` with zero remainder using
  a `mod` test:
  if it is, there is no point in continuing with the inner, `j` loop.
- The next thing to consider is what should be the upper limit of the
  loop `for j := ... to ...` should be.  It is pointless to consider values
  of `j` which are higher than the square root of `i` for the obvious reason
  that if `i` has an intger factor greater than that, it must also have one
  which is lower.
- If the `j` loop completes without finding a factor, `i` is prime.

Try coding the inner, `j` loop, and you will see how the result is vastly
simpler (and more predictable) than your existing code, and with very few
opportunities for coding error, and vastly simpler to debug because execution
just "falls" through it for each value of `i`.

Btw, I completely agree with @TomBrunberg about structured coding as a general proposition, but I think that the two nested `for` loops you need here don't really need separating into different procedures/functions, though you might try 
that once you've got the code working properly.

Answer (score 0):

The causes of your error are a mix between the fact that the problem is highly depending on your input and that you are not treating some cases in `else` causes.

As an example, I ran your program with `a=20` and `b=30`. The program ran into the `for` loop, which is correct. However, the `(b>2) and (b<=10)` condition is false, which made the compiler go to the `else` branch. However, the first thing it met there was `while (q>=2) and (b<=10)` which is, from the start, false. There it bounces back as you said in your question.

With `a=2` and `b=9`, your program has a total different behavior.

How to fix it? I guess you first have to clarify what you want. Then, I think, the fix will be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Your program lacks structure because the whole program is crammed in the main procedure.

As a consequence of the previous, it has too many 'indentation levels' or 'logical chains' to be readable and manageable. With indentation levels or logical chains I mean e.g. your:

```
'for<condition> - if<condition> - while<condition> - if<condition> - if<condition> - if<condition> - writeln().
```

Because of the long chains of conditions, it is hard to evaluate what a change will effect, and you might find yourself deeper and deeper in trouble, when you try to fix something.

I suggest you ditch what you have now, and divide your program into procedures / functions according to main operations: for example  `GetUserEntry(var a, b: integer)`, `function IsPrime(x: integer): boolean`, `procedure ShowResult()` and the main program (`GetUserEntry`, `for a to b if IsPrime then add to outstring`, `ShowResult(outstring)`).

Finally, format your code to be readable using proper indentation.

Comment: I can't use any of that because my professor asks us to do it this way, because we haven't been taught about it. It sucks.

Comment: In that case @Martyn s answer is the best to apply.